# How Do I select from DropDown Menu that Does not have an ID

Tags: vba, excel

My Code:

```
Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
      Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      IE.Visible = True
................
IE.Navigate "https://www./CTMT"


      Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:0:03"))

      Set HTMLDoc2 = IE.document
      HTMLDoc2.getElementsByName("merchID")(0).Value = "aa"
      HTMLDoc2.getElementByName("selDate")(0).SelectedIndex = 2

      'HTMLDoc2.getElementByName("selDate")(0).FireEvent ("onchange")
      'HTMLDoc2.getElementsByName("Search")(0).Submit

      HTMLDoc2.Forms("onlineReportFormBean").Submit

      Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop

    End Sub
```

Q) I am able to fill the text box next to Merchant ID but I am Unable to select the second Index...May2016 using the above code.

```
HTMLDoc2.getElementByName("selDate")(0).SelectedIndex = 2
```

Above line gives the error : Object doesnt support this property or method

Q2) I am also unable to click on "search".

```
HTMLDoc2.Forms("onlineReportFormBean").Submit
```

Line gives automation error..

Comment: It's getElementsByName, you need the s.

Comment: Yes...My Bad... what about the search button?? How do I submit this page?

Comment: Use getElementsbyName, find the element, then click it. e.g. ie.document.getelementsbyName("Submit")(0).click

Comment: Okay thnx...both worked... I was using Element instead of Elements

Comment: Quick Question: What does the zero represent getElementByName("selDate")(0)?

Comment: This: getElementByName("selDate")(0) means nothing. Use getElementsByName. The "s" means there can be many elements that go by the same name. The name property isn't unique like the ID property is, as such when you call it, it returns a collection of elements share that name in common. It could be 1 or 1000 elements, it depends on the page. The (0) specifies the first element in the collection you selected by name. The collection's index starts at 0.